# python error with substring assignment

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, substring

I have:

```
LETTERS = ['A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O','P','Q','R','S','T','U','V','W','X','Y','Z']
results = ['BAN', 'ANA', 'PEE', 'L']
length = len(LETTERS)

for segment in results:
    # get the numerical position of the character
    first_char = LETTERS.index(segment[0])
    # get the shift number
    first_char = (first_char + 0) % length
    #first character shift
    segment[0] = LETTERS[first_char]
```

I am getting an error as follows:

```
  segment[0] = LETTERS[first_char]
TypeError: 'str' object does not support item assignment
```

if I modify this program so that it's not in a for loop it works but in the loop is where I get the message. Why is that?

Comment: A string is immutable. You can't change a character in it.

Answer (score 0):

you are using `foreach` kind of loop.

`for segment in results:`

segment is an item in array and you cannot index it (like you do `segment[0]`).

Answer (score 0):

Strings are immutable, so you can't assign to an index.

You can create a new string like this

```
segment = LETTERS[first_char] + segment[1:]
```

But that won't replace the value in results. To do that you need to enumerate

```
for i, segment in enumerate(results):
    ...
    result[i] = LETTERS[first_char] + segment[1:]
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of changing the (immutable) string, you need to create a new string and replace the old one:

```
LETTERS = ['A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O','P','Q','R','S','T','U','V','W','X','Y','Z']
results = ['BAN', 'ANA', 'PEE', 'L']
length = len(LETTERS)

for i in range(len(results)):
    # get the numerical position of the character
    first_char = LETTERS.index(results[i][0])
    # get the shift number
    first_char = (first_char + 0) % length
    #first character shift
    results[i] = LETTERS[first_char] + results[i][1:]
```

Comment: Wouldn't `results[i] = LETTERS[first_char] + results[i][1:]`

Comment: be `results[i][0] = LETTERS[first_char] + results[i][1:]` to access the first character and not just the first item in the lis 'BAN'?

Comment: No, you want to access the first item. Like I (and the other answerers) have said, you cannot just access the first character. This method will assign a new string to that index in the list.

Comment: `results[i][1:]` means every character in the original string *except* the first character; `LETTERS[first_char]` is the new first character; so, `LETTERS[first_char] + results[i][1:]` is your desired new string, and it's being reassigned to results[i], effectively overwriting the original string.